# How to disable eslint rule-of-hook when using hook outside a React component

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have an api service that use React-Query's hook. So I have useQuery() inside normal functions. Eslint goes mad because of this, but quite frankly, I don't see anything wrong with this. I'm not using React's core hook outside components.

How to disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks in this case?

exemple:

```js
const getPaginatedConversations = async (cursor = 0, userId: string) => {
  try {
    const res = await api.get(
      `/conversations/?userId=${userId}&start=${cursor}&limit=20`
    );
    return res.data.messages;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error.conversations.fetch_all");
  }
};


const fetchConversations: MessageService["fetchConversations"] = (
  userId: string
) => {
  const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    isFetchingNextPage,
    fetchNextPage,
    error,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(
    ["conversations", userId],
    ({ pageParam }) => getPaginatedConversations(pageParam, userId),
    { getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {return lastPage.cursor + 20} }
  );
  return {
    data: data ? formatData(data.pages) : [],
    loading: isLoading,
    isFetchingMore: isFetchingNextPage,
    error: error && error.message,
    fetchMore: fetchNextPage,
    canFetchMore: !isLoading && !isFetchingNextPage && !error, 
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not using React's core hook outside components.

It may be indirect, but you **are** using react's core hooks. You're calling `useQuery` outside a component, and `useQuery` is going to turn right around and [call useState, useRef, and useEffect](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/master/src/react/useBaseQuery.ts#L13). That's the reason they used the naming convention of hooks: to alert you and the lint rule that the function is calling react hooks, and thus it needs to follow the same [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) as calling react hooks directly, or it will not work correctly.

In other words, from the information you've provided, the lint rule seems to be doing its job and alerting you to a bug in your code.

Comment: But is it really a bug? It works fine with this configuration. Abstracting all the api call in separate function is so much cleaner than having the useQuery inside my components.

Comment: `But is it really a bug? ` probably, though since you didn't share the code that's using `useQuery`, i'm only making an educated guess. useQuery depends on useState, useRef, and useEffect to do its job, and those will not work if called outside of rendering a component.

Comment: I've added an exemple in the main post.

Comment: `fetchConversations` looks like it will fail if called outside of rendering a function component. How are you calling it? You say it "works fine", so maybe you already are calling it from inside a function component and just need to update the name to be a custom hook name (ie, start it with "use", as in "useFetchConversations").

Comment: I call it this way, inside a component: `const { conversations, loading,  isFetchingMore, error, fetchMore, canFetchMore } = fetchConversations(id);` So yes, technically, useQuery can't fail because the parent is a component. But eslint keeps going mad. This is why I would like to disable it.

Comment: If you're calling it inside a component, then you're using it correctly. You just need to name it correctly too. Change the name from fetchConversations to anything starting with "use", and the lint rule will begin applying the rules of hooks to it.

Comment: instead of renaming it with "useSomething", isn't there a way to silence eslint regarding with specific use?

Comment: There is. I don't recommend it. By using the naming convention, humans looking at your code can understand that your code must follow the rules of hooks, and eslint can point it out to them if they forget. If you disable eslint, someone (including future you) can misuse the code you've written and eslint cannot point it out. To disable eslint, use `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks`.

Answer (score 0):

React hooks are supposed to be used inside functional components. You shouldn't try to use it outside the component, which indicates a bug/flaw in your logic because custom hooks use react's core hooks underneath.

You can define `fetchConversations` inside the component.

Comment: yes `because custom hooks use react's core hooks underneath`